# print an array whose length and dimensions are unknown

Tags: java, c++, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I was asked at an interview to print all the elements of an array whose length and dimensions are unknown. i could not find a way but the interviewer said that it can be done. can any one tell how it can be done?

Comment: A) Pick a language; They aren't all the same. B) Show what you've tried / thought of.

Comment: Please tell your interviewer he asks bad questions

Comment: Tell me, did you studied C++ & Java?

Answer (score 2):

In Java the size of the array is always known.  You cannot create an array without a `length` so the question doesn't make sense in Java.

In C++, you either know the length or you don't.  You can't be in a position that you don't know the length but you can work it out, because then you would know the length.  What they could mean is that there is a sentinel value like 0, rather than being stored as a length, but once you find such a sentential value you know the length.

Answer (score 2):

The question really only makes sense in C++, so that's what I'll address. Assuming you really have an array (not just a pointer to the beginning of an array) you can do it. The trick is to pass the array (by reference) to a function template that can deduce its size from its type:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, size_t N>
void print(T (&array)[N]) { 
    for (size_t i=0; i<N; i++)
        std::cout << array[i] << "\n";
}

int main() {
    int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    char array2[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

    print(array1);
    std::cout << "\n";
    print(array2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the length of an automatic or static storage array can be considered to be *known*, and you can obtain it, either by using the `sizeof` operator, or with templates. On the other hand, you cannot determine the length of a dynamically allocated array, nor can you determine the length of an array when all you have is a pointer to such array. This also applies to automatic or static storage arrays in contexts where they decay to pointers.

To illustrate the first point, here's an example of a function that prints the elements of an automatic storage array:

```
template< class T, size_t N >
void print_array(const T (&array)[N] )
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    std::cout << i <<" ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And an example of usage:

```
int [] data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
print_array(data);
```

Now, to answer the question in C++ there is no standards compliant way which does not invoke undefined behaviour to print the elements of an array whose size you don't know or cannot find out via the same mechanism you would use to print it. Printing the elements requires that you have or , obtain, knowledge of the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't have any information about type of array, like when you only have Object reference to it. In that case...

In Java there is `java.lang.reflect.Array` class that can be used to help you with arrays, like get its elements, its length and so on. Also you can use `java.lang.Class` class to get informations about type of any object's class, like `isArray()` and if it is array `getComponentType()` to see class of array elements (for `String[]` it will return `String`).

Here is some code example that can be used to print elements from one or multidimensional arrays

```
public static void printElements(Object someArray) {
    if (someArray == null) {
        System.out.print(someArray);
        return;
    }

    Class<?> clazz = someArray.getClass();
    if (clazz.isArray()) {// we need to iterate over its elements
        int length = Array.getLength(someArray);
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            // lets test if array is multidimensional
            if (clazz.getComponentType().isArray()) {// if element is also
                                                        // arrays
                // we can process them with our method
                printElements(Array.get(someArray, i));
            } else {// here element is not an array
                // so we can print it
                System.out.print(Array.get(someArray, i));
                if (i < length - 1)
                    System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    } else {
        System.out.println(someArray+" is not an array!");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int[][][] arr = { { { 1, 2, 3 }, null, { 4, 5 } }, {} };
printElements(arr);
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3]null[4, 5]][]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an Iterator over an array in java, you could use one of the direct implementations out there. For example:

Apache Commons Collections ArrayIterator

Or, this one, if you'd like to use generics:

com.Ostermiller.util.ArrayIterator

Note that if you want to have an Iterator, over primitive types, you can't, because a primitive type can't be a generic parameter. E.g., if you want an Iterator, you have to use an Iterator instead, which will result in a lot of autoboxing and -unboxing if that's backed by an int[].